# get an old repo pushed instead of the new one

Tags: git

I have a git repo named A.

Now I created another one, named B, from the website.

Using the CMD, I went to my project B folder and I did;

```
git remote add originB master xxxxx.git
git push -u originB master
```

The problem is that in the new repoB, I found old project A.

I'm pretty sure I am in right local directory, so why the old repo is being pushed instead of the new one?

Comment: This is unclear.  If you cloned A, and then pushed it to B, why are you surprised that B looks like A?

Comment: I didn't clone A, I created a new repo B, & my local project is B different than A

Comment: So where does A come into it?

Comment: that what I don't undrestand, I deleted the repoB & repeated the steps above, same result

Comment: Hmm.  Are you sure you're not in a subdirectory of a local clone of A?  i.e. `git clone A.git; mkdir foo; cd foo; git clone B.git;`.  That could lead to various weirdnesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you copy the directory and the .git hidden directory is in there..

if you want to switch to another repo from the same project folder structure the command

```
git init
```

will make .git re-initialization.. all the checkouts will be gone away.

ex:

```
cd route_to/A_project/
git init 
git remote add originB master xxxx.git
git push -u origin master..
```

if you need to copy some of your projectB to projectA without losing the chekouts. then create a temp directory.. ex.

```
mkdir tempdir
cd tempdir
git clone https://myrepoB.git
cp * -R ../
cd ..
git status 
git add (add the needed)
git commit -m "this checkout contains the last checkout of B project"
```